# Can I change/"rebind" the default WinRT system brushes/palette colors to match my app?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

and would it be best practice to do it this way?

So for instance, `HyperlinkPointerOverBrush` defines a dark blue/green and this is the default brush colour my app inherits for when your mouse/"finger" is hovered over a link. But can the colour assignment from dark blue/green easily be changed to something else?

(Below illustrates the list of system brushes my app has reference to)
[image]

I tried setting `HyperlinkPointerOverBrush` to something different in my `App.xaml`:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="HyperlinkPointerOverBrush" Color="#FF0A2562"/>
```

within my metro app, but to no avail; my links still stayed the default dark blue/green.

Any thoughts on how I would approach this? and also best practices on defining your app's System Brushes aka. "Palette" you wish to use on Windows 8 Metro-style WinRT apps? (that's a mouthful)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The controls that come out of the box in winrt assemblies have styles and templates that use resources from these assemblies. The one simple thing you can do to change it is to set RequestedTheme="Light" in app.xaml. To change arbitrary brushes you would also need to modify the styles/templates themselves by overriding them explicitly when you use the controls.

You can extract the default templates in the design view context menu by going to "Edit Template"/"Edit a Copy...". You would then modify the extracted styles using your theme resources.

You can use a predefined set of resources or a theme by merging it in your App.xaml/MergedDictionaries, as Common/StandardStyles.xaml is in the basic templates. Possibly if you define multiple theme resource dictionaries that use the same keys - you could dynamically alter the merged dictionaries in App.xaml to change the theme at runtime.

Comment: Ok thanks Filip. I'll wait to see if I receive any more answers before accepting yours.

Answer (score 4):

You can override all system brushes, just by putting a brush with the same key into your resources:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBoxItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Green" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

A list of all system brushes for WinRT can be found here:
http://www.win8tutorial.net/styling/windows-8-1-theme-resources/

The most tricky thing is to find the right brushes to override, since there are more than hundred of it.

Greetings

Christian
http://www.wpftutorial.net

Comment: Thanks Christian, as said I did try overwriting the `HyperlinkPointerOverBrush` for instance, but it did not work. Will try again another time. Thanks